# ext directory implementation

Tags: c, directory, fs

I've been trying to implement a simple file system. After reading a lot of information about the ext file systems, I managed to end up with super simple implementation, which can not work with names on files, but only inode numbers. I recently started researching how to design structure which would allow directories and files. I'm. not sure if it is better to implement directories as a file containing information about the files in it or every file structure to have some kind of `next` and to end up with linked list like design.

I would really like to read your suggestions.

Note: I'm trying to do this thing without any built-in structures in the Linux kernel and only the standard library of C.

Thank you for your time. Have a nice day.

Comment: The traditional Unix directory structure is pretty simple, and likewise simple to implement.  You just want a mapping of names to inode numbers.  The original [V7 Unix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Version_7_Unix) directory used 16 bytes per directory entry: 14 for the name, and 2 for the inode number.  You could use something like that, or a simple text file, one directory entry per line.

Comment: The tricky part will be updating the directory when files are deleted or renamed.  For simplicity (at some loss in efficiency) you could rewrite the entire directory file each time.  Or, you could adopt a convention where you overwrite deleted/unused entries with some distinct pattern.  Have fun!

Comment: This is not really an appropriate question for [so]. You should ask specific questions about actual code you've written, not general design advice. A good SO question should be one with an objectively correct answer, and this question invites opinionated answers.

Comment: FYI, much of the standard C library is not available in the kernel, although there are substitutes for some of the simple functions (like those in `string.h`).